# Files downloading with page content

Tags: .net, vb.net, mime-types

I have an application in which a user is able to upload and download files, however when uploading and downloading text files im getting an issue. When viewing the file after it has downloaded i can see the original contents of the file at the top but then below that is the html content of the page it was downloaded from?

Here is the logic for the download:

```
''' <summary>
''' Downloads a file to the browser
''' </summary>
''' <param name="serverFilePath"></param>
Public Sub DownloadFile(serverFilePath As String)

    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(serverFilePath)
    Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(serverFilePath)

    Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
    Dim response As HttpResponse = context.Response
    response.BufferOutput = True
    response.Clear()
    'Returns the mime type for the given extension
    response.ContentType = MimeTypeHelper.GetMimeType(ext)
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";")
    response.TransmitFile(serverFilePath)
    response.Flush()
    context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

End Sub
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried Response.End instead of CompleteRequest?

Comment: Thanks for response yes this worked, see @Nickthename's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
response.ClearContent()
response.ClearHeaders()
response.AppendHeader("content-length", bytes.Length.ToString())
response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";")
response.ContentType = MimeTypeHelper.GetMimeType(ext)
response.BinaryWrite(bytes) 'Where bytes is ann array of bytes representing the file
response.Flush()
response.Close()
```

Works for me

Comment: Thank you this worked! It looks like it was the last line that sorted my issue, response.close(). Are you able to explain why this might have been my issue?

Comment: Because if you tell you want to complete request you want also the page to be rendered (appending it into the response that is meant to be an attachment). Instead you need just to close the response so that in the response there is only the file. Please check my answer as it solved. Thank you.

Comment: Sure ill check it now, i didnt originally as it solved my problem but didnt answer my question. Your comment however did, combined they are the perfect answer.